# REST Architecture - Resources and Methods

Tags: rest, resources, methods

In REST based architectures what's the difference between a resource and a method. Is there one?

Answer (score 2):

A resource is something your application defines; they're very similar to objects. A method is one of the HTTP verbs, e.g., `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`. They are similar to methods that get invoked on your resource.

I really recommend you read [Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-Based Architectures](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) (Dr. Fielding's dissertation, where he defines REST) and/or [RESTful Web Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260), which does a stellar job of showing how to put the theory into practice.

Answer (score 2):

Reading [RESTify DayTrader](http://bitworking.org/news/201/RESTify-DayTrader) helped the concept sink in for me. He explains pretty decently how to go from a description of "actions" to a series of URIs and Methods on those URIs.

Comment: The DayTrader article was a really nice article introducing RESTify-ing an API.

Answer (score 0):

A resource is an interesting piece of state that a distributed application designer has decided to create a URL for.

```
http://example.org/foo
```

may be an identifier of a resource. As may,

```
http://example.org/foos?state=open
```

A method is an action or operation that can be performed on that resource.  e.g.

```
GET http://example.org/foo
```